# Diferença entre /> e </

Tags: html

Qual é a diferença entre usar `/>` e `</` para fechar uma tag em HTML?

**Exemplo1:**

```
<div>
  <img src="caminho"/>
</div>
```

**Exemplo2:**

```
<div>
  <img src="caminho"></img>
</div>
```

Sei que ambas fazem o mesmo, no entanto entre as duas opções existe alguma que seja a mais correcta? e qual a razão?

Comment: Não existe "a mais correta", são casos diferentes.